# Approximation argument for Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider $(\mathbb{R}^N,\mu)$ where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded subset. It is known that
$$\mu(\Omega) =\sup\{\mu(K): K\subset\Omega, K \mbox{ compact}\}.$$
My question is: if I take into account the integral over $\Omega$, could I always write that
$$\int_K \dots dx\leq\int_{\Omega}\cdots dx?$$
The advantage is that I can work on a compact set. Then, passing to the supremum, could I obtain the above inequality?

(I mean, a sort of approximation argument).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ .
If $f\geq 0$ in $\Omega$, then, for any $K \subseteq \Omega$, $K$ compact, we have that

$$\int_K f dx\leq\int_{\Omega} f dx$$

**Proof**: Given any $K \subseteq \Omega$, $K$ compact, we have that $f\geq 0$ in $\Omega \setminus K$ and so
$$ \int_{\Omega\setminus K} f dx \geq 0$$
So
$$\int_K f dx\leq \int_K f dx\ + \int_{\Omega\setminus K} f dx = \int_{\Omega} f dx$$
This completes the proof. $\square$

However, if we don't know that $f\geq 0$ in $\Omega$, then we can not assure that
$\int_K f dx\leq\int_{\Omega} f dx$. Here is a simple counter-example:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $f=-\chi_\Omega$ , then, for any $K \subseteq \Omega$, $K$ compact, then, since $\mu(K) < \mu(\Omega) $, we have
$$\int_K (-\chi_\Omega) dx = -\mu(K) > -\mu(\Omega) = \int_{\Omega} (-\chi_\Omega) dx$$

Comment: could you please show me why if $f\geq 0$, thus the inequality holds always true? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @C.Bishop , You are welcome. I have updated my answer to include the details of why if $f \geq 0$ then the inequality $\int_K f dx\leq\int_{\Omega} f dx$ holds. Please, let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Very detailed proof, thank you again Ramiro.